# Unsure why conditional column transform is not identifying values to update (Text.Contains)

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table of people records with various demographic information (Race, Ethnicity, Gender etc.).

For `null` values in [Ethnicity] (i.e., Hispanic Y/N), I want to search the corresponding [Race] value for a string "non-Hispanic", since for some records these have been stored as a combined value under [Race] (e.g., `"White (non-Hispanic)"`). and I'd like to clean/normalize both fields ([Race] is cleaned in a separate downstream step).

However, I'm unsure why my code is not successfully identifying matches to the first two conditions, since I know there are many instances of `"White (non-Hispanic)"` at the very least:

```
cleanData = 
    Table.ReplaceValue(rawData, each [Ethnicity], each
        if [Ethnicity] = null and (
            Text.Contains([Race],"non-Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or 
            Text.Contains([Race],"not Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            then "Non-hispanic" else
        if [Ethnicity] = null and 
            Text.Contains([Race], "hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
            then "Hispanic" else
        [Ethnicity], Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Ethnicity"}
        ),
```

Both fields are type Text, and I'm not hitting an error - just a lack of expected behavior. The `null` values in [Ethnicity] are unchanged.

Sample input:

| Race | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| White | Yes |
| Asian | No |
| White (non-Hispanic) | Decline to respond |
| White (non-Hispanic) | *null* |
| White (Hispanic) | *null* |
| Asian | *null* |

Sample output:

| Race | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| White | Yes |
| Asian | No |
| White (non-Hispanic) | Decline to Respond |
| White (non-Hispanic) | **No** |
| White (Hispanic) | **Yes** |
| Asian | *null* |

Comment: Please provide sample input data in text format and expected output and someone will be able to help.

Comment: `Replacer.ReplaceValue`   ***`null`*** is a value, not a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the Replacer.ReplaceText which should be Replacer.ReplaceValue

```
cleanData =  Table.ReplaceValue(rawData,  each [Ethnicity], each
    if [Ethnicity] = null then 
        if (Text.Contains([Race],"non-Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or  Text.Contains([Race],"not Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        then "Non-hispanic" else 
        if  Text.Contains([Race], "hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  then "Hispanic"  else [Ethnicity]
    else [Ethnicity]
 ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Ethnicity"}),
```

or

```
cleanData =  Table.ReplaceValue(rawData,  each [Ethnicity], each
    if [Ethnicity] = null and
        (Text.Contains([Race],"non-Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or  Text.Contains([Race],"not Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
        then "Non-hispanic" else 
         if [Ethnicity] = null  and Text.Contains([Race], "hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  then "Hispanic"  else [Ethnicity]
 ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Ethnicity"}),
```

Answer (score 0):

@horseyride you can abstract it to use a list of any size

```
    Text.ContainsAny = (source as text, searchStrings as list) as logical =>
        let
            matches = List.Transform( searchStrings, (string) =>
                Text.Contains(source, string, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
        in
            List.AnyTrue(matches),
```

then you can write

```
if [Ethnicity] = null and Text.ContainsAny( [Race], {"non-hispanic", "not-hispanic"} ) then "Non-hispanic"
else ...
```

[image]

I here's another way using `Table.AddColumn`, then rename. That might sound worse than using replacing a column, in-place. After testing, I was getting the same final folded SQL query -- using either method.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document( Binary.Decompress( Binary.FromText( "i45WCs/ILElVUNJRikwtVorViVZyLM5MzAMJ+OWD+RAFGnn5eboemcUFiXmZyZogaZfU5JzMvFSFknyFotTigvy8FLzKkSUxJeCWoppRgm5GLAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64 ), Compression.Deflate ) ),
        let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Race = _t, Ethnicity = _t]
    ),
    // eliminate whitespace, or control chars
    #"Changed Type"   = Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source, {{"Race", type text}, {"Ethnicity", type nullable text}} ),
    #"Cleaned Text"   = Table.TransformColumns( Source, {{"Ethnicity", Text.Clean, type nullable text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue( #"Cleaned Text", "", null, Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Ethnicity"} ),

    merge_columns = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type",
        "Ethnicity2",
        (row) =>
            let
                isBlank = row[Ethnicity] = null or row[Ethnicity] = "",
                race = row[Race],
                replacement =
                    if (
                        Text.Contains(race, "non-Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        or Text.Contains(race, "not-Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    ) then
                        "Non-Hispanic"
                    else if Text.Contains(race, "Hispanic", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then
                        "Hispanic"
                    else
                        race
            in
                if isBlank then
                    replacement
                else
                    race,
        type text
    ),
    #"ReplaceColumns" = Table.RenameColumns(
        Table.RemoveColumns(merge_columns, {"Ethnicity"}), {{"Ethnicity2", "Ethnicity"}}
    )
in
    #"ReplaceColumns"
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer was geared to the level of the question